# BCP Command using SQL: destination location is another computer in the network

Tags: sql, bcp

I am using BCP Utility to fetch the data from my sql table and dump in text file. I can able to dump the query result to text file in the system where sql server is running. But, actually i want the destination text file to be created in another system in the network. if i give the destination path location of another system, i am always getting error, such as,

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Unable to open BCP host data-file

How to save the generated text file in some other system in the network. Please advise

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

BCP will behave like any other program regarding file access. Find out why you cannot access that network location. Try creating an empty file in Windows Explorer and you will also receive an error that is hopefully a bit more explicit.

Comment: I tried to find out in google, asked to provide SQL service account permission for the destination folder. I have provided that also. SQL Server's 'Log on As' is configured to system's 'Admin' account. so, it will come and access the other system as a same user, am i right?

Comment: SQL Server does not access the bcp output file. bcp.exe does. bcp.exe runs under the user which you start it under which is probably the same user that you have logged in with.

Comment: yeah, i see a bcp.exe is running in Task mgr and it runs as the Admin user in the Sql installed system. how should i check whether the bcp in that system can able to access another system in the network now?

Comment: Try creating an empty file in Windows Explorer and you will also receive an error that is hopefully a bit more explicit.

Comment: i am sorry, but i dont know whether i understood what you said and tried or not, sorry if i did wrong. i have just created an empty file in the destination system (other system in network) from the sql installed system and i can create and access it. Is this what you want me to do?

Comment: Create the file from the same system you are running bcp.exe on with the same user. Then you should get the same error. Alternatively, use can use Process Monitor to find the exact error that bcp.exe hit. It is a Sysinternals Tool.